# how to fetch data using zend db select if data is in "Portuguese"?

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework, select

how to fetch data using zend db select if data is in `"Portuguese"`?
"Amapá - AP" Having this text in database. "á" is creating problem.

I am using the query:

```
 SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE state_name LIKE 'Amapá - AP'
```

It runs properly in database but create create problem with zend db select.
Could anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: What kind of problem is created with zend db select? What error is returned? Please be more specific when asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to handle special characters with Zend_Db then you should set the charset type "utf8". To set the charset type utf8, add following property in your config file:

**resources.db.params.charset=utf8**

now everything will work fine.

Comment: or resources.multidb.yourdb.charset = "utf8"

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to bind params to query

your query should be

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE state_name LIKE ?");
$searchFor = "Amapá - AP";
/* or
$searchFor = "%Amapá - AP%";
$searchFor = "%Amapá - AP";
*/
$query->bind_param("s",$searchFor);
```

For more details and examples about using **bind_params** [find here](http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)